# Error while importing scikits.talkbox

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, signal-processing, scikits, mfcc

I want to use scikits.talkbox, but i get the following error while import scikits.talkbox.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/seref/Desktop/machine learning codes/MFCC/main.py", line 3, in 
>       from scikits.talkbox.features.mfcc import mfcc
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scikits/talkbox/**init**.py", line 3, in 
>       from tools import *
>   ImportError: No module named 'tools'

code sample

```
import scipy.io.wavfile
from scikits.talkbox.features.mfcc import mfcc

sample_rate, X = scipy.io.wavfile.read("data/test_1.wav")
ceps, mspec, spec = mfcc(X)
```

I use following code when installing scikits.talkbox

> sudo pip3 install scikits.talkbox

Operation system ubuntu 16.10
python interpreter 3.5.2+

Comment: This lib looks heavily outdated / deprecated (last change 8 years ago) and i would not be surprised to see that it's python 2 only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want MFCCs in Python 3, [librosa](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.mfcc.html) is probably the better library of your choice.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will use librosa